# Ubuntu not connecting to wireless

Tags: wireless, internet, connection

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed on my dell laptop for couple of months(didn't want it but my company forced it).  Rescently I am having some issues in connecting to some wireless networks. So far I have been able to connect to any wireless network. But at present I am not able to connect to my new home wireless , however with same laptop I am able to connect to office wireless and my friends wireless.The wireless is detected by Ubuntu and is present in the list of connection but can't connect, if I click it it is instantly removed not even asking for password. i am able to connect to my home wireless through my iPhone which means that there is no issue with my home wireless connection setup.
Even if I use the iPhone as hotspot still not able to connect via Ubuntu

Request some help.

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless card from the terminal: lspci -nn | grep 0280 Thanks.

Comment: Here is the output of the command  lspci -nn | grep 0280
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] [8086:0082] (rev 34)

Comment: the output of nm-tool   --- >> - Device: wlan0 ---------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            iwlwifi
  State:             disconnected
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        08:11:96:C0:1C:48

  Capabilities:
   
  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

 Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    dlink123:      Infra, E8:94:F6:3C:43:24, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 54 WPA2

Answer (score 1):

You do not have an Atheros wireless card, so the ath9k.conf file is ineffective. Since the problem is only with your *new* home wireless, I suspect it's a configuration problem in the router.

First, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, I have better luck with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection.

Make sure the router is set to automatic B, G, N  and, if it's capable, AC speeds, not locked to N and certainly not locked to AC since the Intel wireless device you have is not AC capable.

After making these changes, reboot the router.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue once. As far as i know, ubuntu can't connect to *WPA **2** PSK* wifi security. 
Try to change your wireless adapter security setting to *WPA PSK*. I tried this and it works now.

Comment: My wireless devices connect to WPA2 perfectly well.

Comment: @AlKaef -- yes the wireless connection I am trying to connect is a WPA2 connection dlink123:      Infra, E8:94:F6:3C:43:24, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 54 WPA2

Comment: @Avishek have you tried to change it to WPA?

Answer (score -1):

Is the Wireless turned on? Can you run this script:

```
echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
sudo modprobe -rfv ath9k
sudo modprobe -v ath9k
```

Comment: How on earth would you believe he has an Atheros wireless card??

Comment: I also used this on a other wireless card.

Comment: echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf 
options ath9k nohwcrypt=1




sudo modprobe -rfv ath9k





sudo modprobe -v ath9k
insmod /lib/modules/3.2.0-51-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/3.2.0-51-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_hw.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/3.2.0-51-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_common.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/3.2.0-51-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k.ko nohwcrypt=1 nohwcrypt=1